# "invalid character constant" error

Tags: java

```
//takes out random letters if taking out all of the vowles does not get it to the right number of charachters
    while(tweet.length()> TWEET_LENGTH && vowles == 0){
        int i = ranNum.nextInt(tweet.lenght());
        char c = tweet.charAt(i);
        if ((c !=''))
        {
            tweet = tweet.substring(0,i) + tweet.substring(i+1);
```

this is the code i have and i keep getting an error at this point

```
 if ((c !=''))
```

where the two single quotes are saying "invalid character constant"   I'm not sure what i am doing wrong. any tips?

Comment: `tweet.lenght()` won't compile either

Comment: Yes, Elliott is right there is no empty character literal, You must be using some other valid character literal instead of what you are using(Empty character literal).

Comment: Just for confirmation, is the line `if ((c !=''))` meant to be checking for spaces?  If not, what is it supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 3):

There is no empty character. Based on the comment, you should be using 'a', 'e', 'i' ...

Comment: i tried plugging in those and when i try to play the code it still has an error

Comment: all i need to do is take this tweet                                                                    "So the combination is... one, two, three, four, five? That's the stupidest combination I've ever heard in my life! That's the kind of thing an idiot would have on his luggage!"                                                                                          and have code randomly take out characters to shorten it to 140 characters

Comment: If more errors appear, either you're doing something wrong when you try to fix it, or this error was just hiding the other ones because it made the compiler give up.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to make code that will delete random characters until there are only 140

Comment: If you're trying to check for spaces, then use `' '` instead of `''` (with a space in between the quotes.)  Your method seems like it should work, in general.

Comment: when i do that it comes up with this error    java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a blank character.  It is possible to have an empty String - that would be a String with zero characters in it.  But a character always has a value.

Even if your code somehow compiled, it would be checking for an impossibility - `tweet.charAt(i)` is going to return the character at location `i`.  How could there not be a character at that location?  (If it was off the end of the String, it would throw an exception.)

If you wanted to check for a space, you could use `' '` instead of `''`.  A space is a valid character that the compiler is happy to let you use.

The following code compiles and runs (but doesn't extract the vowels; you didn't show us that code and it's outside the scope of this question anyway.)  It's almost identical to what you have, except I changed that `''` to `' '` and added the obvious stuff to make it compile.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Answers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random ranNum = new Random();
        String tweet = " \"So the combination is... one, two, three, four, five? That's the stupidest combination I've ever heard in my life! That's the kind of thing an idiot would have on his luggage!\"";
        final int TWEET_LENGTH = 140;

        while(tweet.length() > TWEET_LENGTH){
            int i = ranNum.nextInt(tweet.length());
            char c = tweet.charAt(i);
            if ((c !=' '))
            {
                tweet = tweet.substring(0,i) + tweet.substring(i+1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(tweet);
        System.out.println(tweet.length());
    }
}
```